From php openssl_encrypt to python decrypt
I have some data on DB crypted with php and I have to decode them using python.

algo: AES-256-CBC
padding: OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING
key: SWAGxshpHsDYh_... <<< 32 length string (not byte, not base64)
iv: VtBXhS... <<< 16 length string (not byte, not base64)

Using this PHP function, it works:
openssl_decrypt(
            $value,
            'AES-256-OFB',
            "SWAGxshpHsDYh.....",
            OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING,
            "VtBXh...."
        );

I've to translate this with python.
I've tryed a lot of function from web, chatgpt. They usually use PyCrypto
def openssl_decrypt(self , ciphertext, key, iv):        
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        decrypted_data = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
        plaintext = decrypted_data.rstrip(b'\0')
        return plaintext 

I always got an error.
Common errors are:

ValueError: Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode
TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code
TypeError: from_buffer() cannot return the address of a unicode object

What I need is the equivalent function:
descrypted = self.openssl_decrypt(crypted_data , 'SWAGxshpHsDYh_......' , 'VtBXh....')

Thanks
